# write.format adding extra quotes while writing to a tab delimited hdfs file in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I have a dataframe in pyspark, whose schema and value is as below-

schema-

```
|-- C1: string (nullable = true)
|-- C2: string (nullable = true)
|-- C3: string (nullable = true)
|-- C4: string (nullable = true)
```

data-

```
|C1|C2|C3|C4|
+--+--+--+----
|78|93|   |10|
|12|97|   |20|
|23|93|   |10|
|78|93|   |40|
```

My column C3 is column with three spaces. (To be more sure  i checked the length of this column and it came 3)

Now when i try to write this dataframe to a tab delimited file in hdfs my data comes out to be as -

```
78  93  "   "  10
12  97  "   "  20
23  93  "   "  10
78  93  "   "  40
```

That are extra quotes coming for column C3. I used below command to write the dataframe:

```
outp.write.format('csv').option("delimiter","\t").option("quoteMode",None).save(path="path.txt")
```

I tried all the solution i could find but none helped. Also i want to write my column C3  as three spaces only, since I am dealing with a fixed length file I  cannot increase or decrease length of any column.

Please if any one has any solution, help me with this.

spark version I am using-1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

One workaround, is to use a different character to substitute space

```
df2 = df1.replace("   ","***","c3")
df2.show()

+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
| 78| 93|***| 10|
| 12| 97|***| 20|
| 23| 93|***| 30|
+---+---+---+---+
```

You can then substitute it back, during your select operation on the dataframe.

Comment: This will not work for me because i have to write my output to a file and that file needs to be send to end user  , so I cannot write '***'